# Support for partial fill of HTML5 range input in WebKit/Gecko

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

It's like my assignment to create slider control, but without using any external libraries. Only jQuery is allowed (not UI). First I thought I would have to write my own control from the scratch, but then I stumbled into range control from HTML5. It almost looked like win situation, but part of the task is coloring track differently as seen in the image.

[image: assignment]

It really surprised me that IE is winner here since it has `::-ms-fill-lower` pseudo element that can be styled. Unfortunately WebKit/Gecko seems lacking this completely.

Do you think it could be hacked somehow ? I can think of some kind of floating div controlled by javascript that changes it's size, but that seems rather nasty.

If this is not simply possible, can you recommend me some resource how to build this easily on my own? It seems rather complex to handle all dragging & clicking correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it somewhat easily, with Canvas placed under the page, watching for `input` and `change` events on `input[type=radio]` a just drawing rectangle. I also had to detect, if `::-ms-fill-lower` pseudo element is supported and skip this process. I did it like this...

```
try {
    document.querySelector('input[type=radio]::-ms-fill-lower');
    return true;
}
catch {
    return false;
}
```

To draw rectangle I did use jQuery like this...

```
var width = $src.width();
var height = $src.height() + 1
var offset = $src.offset();
var x = offset.left + 1;
var y = offset.top + 1;
var tickSize = width / $src.attr('max');

ctx.fillRect x, y, ($src.val() * tickSize), height
```